# Display datraframe into django template

Tags: python, django, pandas, templates, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on a stadistics portal with `Django` and i'm trying to display a `Dataframe` in my template with the next code:

View.py:

```
def tabla(request):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:alphabeta@localhost:5432/escaladas')
    t='escalado 08/2017'
    sqltable = ps.read_sql_table(t,engine)
    sqltablehead = sqltable.head(n=10)
    table = sqltablehead.to_html(classes='table',index=False,escape=False)
    return render(request,'escalamiento.html',{'table':table})
```

I've tried display that table with a `for` on the template but doesn't show anything and writing `{{table}}` but gives me this https://ibb.co/bVpWw5

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `{{table|safe}}` instead, so the HTML doesn't get [escaped](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#safe).